# Can someone make this modx .htaccess file work for me? I am trying to make friendly URLs work

Tags: internet, apache2, mysql, php

I now have my ModX install working but am unsure how to edit my htaccess file so my friendly urls (trying to alias pages) can anyone help? If you can a copy of my htaccess can be found at http://pastebin.com/7BAwD2PW

PS- My website URL is http://www.nsuchy.tk/ and want nsuchy.tk to redirect to www.nsuchy.tk

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Google says to add the following to `.htaccess` in the web root (probably `/var/www/html`).  This checks for a url starting with (using `^` from basic regular expressions) `nsuchy.tk` and rewriting the url to `www.nsuchy.tk`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nsuchy\.tk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nsuchy.tk/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: If you found this (via "Dr. Google") somewhere, can you please edit in a link to the source?